# inserting variable value in regex in ruby script

Tags: ruby, regex

I am having a ruby script file for patter match. my input string look like below

```
    this.plugin = document.getElementById("pluginPlayer");
```

my regex look like

```
regxPlayerVariable = '(.*?)=.*?document\.getElementById\("#{Regexp.escape(pluginPlayeVariable)}"\)'
```

here **pluginPlayeVariable** is a variable but its not macthing with input string.

if i change my rege and replace variable with its value it's work fine but i can not do that as it's  a run time value which change accordingly.

i also tried some more regex mention below

```
 regxPlayerVariable = '(.*?)=.*?document\.getElementById\("#{pluginPlayeVariable}"\)'
```

so how can i solve this issue?

Comment: Use string concatenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `regxPlayerVariable` is not a `Regexp`, it's a `String`. And the reason why your interpolation does not work is because you are using single quotes. Look:

```
foo = "bar"
puts '#{foo}'   # => #{foo}
puts "#{foo}"   # => bar
puts %q{#{foo}} # => #{foo}
puts %Q{#{foo}} # => bar
puts %{#{foo}}  # => bar
puts /#{foo}/   # => (?-mix:bar)
puts %r{#{foo}} # => (?-mix:bar)
```

Only the last two are actually regular expressions, but here you can see which quoting expressions do interpolation, and which don't.